# Printing a webpage with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, printing

I am using canvas on this project I am working on to allow users to add their signature. I am having a very hard time printing this canvas signature out on paper. Using Google Chrome, the canvas appears nicely in print preview, but does not appear at all on the printed out paper.

I read that in some cases using `toDataURL` and replacing the canvas area with an image, solves the printout problem. However, in my case, doing so did not solve the problem. I was wondering if there is any alternate solution to this issue.

I appreciate any advice.

Many thanks in advance!

This is what I tried:

```
    var sktch = $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
    var cleanCanvas = $('#simple_sketch')[0];

    $('.save-signature').click(function(){
         /* replace canvas with image */
         var canvas = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
         var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         $('.signature-buttons').replaceWith('');
        document.getElementById("signature").value = document.getElementById("simple_sketch").toDataURL("image/png");
         $('#simple_sketch').replaceWith('<img style="border-bottom:2px solid black;" src="'+img+'"/>');
    });
```

Comment: More info please! :)  Is your signature pixelated when printing?  How are you capturing the signature? How are you printing the signature?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm printing the signature along with the rest of the webpage using Google Chrome or Firefox's print dialog. My signature does not print at all (complete white space in that area where the signature should be on the page). Additionally, everything appears great in Chrome's print preview, but not on paper. After the user clicks 'save signature' using the JavaScript code above, the signature is in fact converted to a png image file, however, this does not solve the printing problem of the signature on paper.